# How to serialize a JavaScript associative array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I need to serialize an associative JavaScript array.
It's a simple form of products and a numeric values, but just after building the array seems empty.

The code is here: http://jsbin.com/usupi6/4/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, don't use JS arrays for "associative arrays". Use plain objects:

```
var array_products = {};
```

That is why `$.each` does not work: jQuery recognizes that you pass an *array* and is only iterating over **numerical** properties. All others will be ignored.

An array is supposed to have only entries with numerical keys. You can assign string keys, but a lot of functions will not take them into account.

---

**Better:**

As you use jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.param` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for serialization. You just have to construct the proper input array:

```
var array_products = []; // now we need an array again
$( '.check_product:checked' ).each(function( i, obj ) {
    // index and value
    var num = $(obj).next().val();
    var label = $(obj).next().next().attr( 'data-label' );
    // build array
    if( ( num > 0 ) && ( typeof num !== undefined ) ) {
        array_products.push({name: label, value: num});
    }      
});

var serialized_products = $.param(array_products);
```

No need to implement your own URI encoding function.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/usupi6/7/edit)

---

**Best:**

If you give the input fields a proper `name`:

```
<input name="sky_blue" class="percent_product" type="text" value="20" />
```

you can even make use of [`.serialize()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and greatly reduce the amount of code (I use the [*next adjacent selector <sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)):

```
var serialized_products = $('.check_product:checked + input').serialize();
```

(it will include `0` values though).

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/usupi6/8/edit)

Answer (score 5):

You could serialise it with a [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (or the native [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) if available).

```
var serialised = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify(object)`

As a sidenote there are no associative arrays there are only objects.

Use [json-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to support legacy browsers like IE6 and IE7

Comment: Isn't JSON.stringify only available to more modern browsers? Unless you include a script reference to [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)?

Comment: @AshClarke depends on your definition of modern browsers. It's supported by all current & recent browsers. If you need _legacy_ support use json2 (I've added the link already)

Comment: @Raynos won't `let arr = []; a['foo'] = 'bar'; JSON.stringify(a);` stringify it to '[]'